# PyQt : Editable QFileSystemModel in a QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qfilesystemmodel

I've got this on my file System :

```
 - myFolder
      - mySubFolder
```

1. Within the TreeView I expand the folder **"myFolder"**.
2. Then I rename it as **"myFolder_2"**.
3. And finaly I try to rename the folder **"mySubFolder"** as **"mySubFolder_2"**.

**"mySubFolder_2"** in is no more considered as a folder but as unknown with a size of -1 bytes and I've got the message : *QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: **myFolder***.

Here is the my source code :

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
treeView = QtGui.QTreeView()
fileSystemModel = QtGui.QFileSystemModel(treeView)
fileSystemModel.setReadOnly(False)
treeView.setModel(fileSystemModel)
folder = "."
treeView.setRootIndex(fileSystemModel.setRootPath(folder))
treeView.show()
end = app.exec_()
```

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the root path on the model before setting it on the treeview:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
treeView = QtGui.QTreeView()
fileSystemModel = QtGui.QFileSystemModel(treeView)
fileSystemModel.setReadOnly(False)
root = fileSystemModel.setRootPath('.')
treeView.setModel(fileSystemModel)
treeView.setRootIndex(root)
treeView.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply but the problem is still the same.

Comment: @JeanDalmayrac. Works fine for me on Linux. Must be a Windows issue - a bug in Qt maybe?

Comment: I've got the same issue under Windows and Unix with python 2.6 and PyQt4.5.2.

Comment: Another problem is that if I expand the 2 folders and then I edit the first one, I have a message box saying that the name I have entered can not be used.

Comment: @JeanDalmayrac. After some more testing on Linux (Python 2.7.2, Qt 4.8.0, PyTt 4.9), the problem seems to come and go. There is obviously some updating issue with the internal `QFileSystemWatcher` that the model uses. (NB: A little googling reveals `QFileSystemWatcher` is pretty flaky and is slated for removal in Qt 5).